# Get progressBar to show PDFTextStripper progress

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using the Apache PDFBox to convert a .pdf document to a text file using PDFTextStripper in a 
WinForms C# application.

I've found that the conversion takes approximately 30-seconds to complete. What I want to do is display the progress of the conversion to the user in a C# progressBar.

I've added a backgroundWorker thread to the program, along with the event handlers. 
However, when I call PDFTextStripper in backgroundWorker1_DoWork, the progressBar doesn't report any 
progress *until after* the conversion has occurred. (sample code shown below)

Can anyone suggest a better way to show the progress in progressBar1? Thank you.

After copying my .pdf file to its location, I check that the file was copied successfully, then call the conversion method.

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\My PDF Folder\myFile.pdf))
{
    string myFile = @"C:\My PDF Folder\myFile.pdf";
    Tuple<string> tuple = Tuple.Create(myFile);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(tuple);//convert from .pdf to .txt file.
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 20)
    {
        Tuple<string> tupleArgs = (Tuple<string>)e.Argument;
        string myFile = tupleArgs.Item1.ToString();
        string tempText = PDFText(myFile);//The PDFTextStripper method
        //Report the progress
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.FileName = @"C:\My PDF Folder\myFile.txt";
        using (Stream s = File.Open(sfd.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
            sw.Write(tempText);
    }
}

private static String PDFText(String PDFFilePath)
{
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(PDFFilePath);
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    string text = stripper.getText(doc);
    doc.close();
    return text;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

public void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've set things up okay. When you've got a bunch of stuff happening in a `BackgroundWorker` thread, it's still happening in a single thread, one line of code after the other. You won't lock up your UI thread, which is good, but you've still got to wait for one line of code to run before another one runs.

Considering your code, whatever's going on in `PDFText()` will have to complete before the next line runs and reports progress back to the UI thread (which is what `ReportProgress()` does):

```
string tempText = PDFText(myFile);

backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
```

Just flip the two lines, so you report progress immediately before doing the long-running stuff in `PDFText()`:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

string tempText = PDFText(myFile);
```

---

Another observation... there's no need to instantiate a `SaveFileDialog` here. Just use the file path directly:

```
using (Stream s = File.Open(@"C:\My PDF Folder\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
        sw.Write(tempText);
```

Better yet, and even shorter:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\My PDF Folder\myFile.txt", tempText);  // overwrite the file

File.AppendAllText(@"C:\My PDF Folder\myFile.txt", tempText); // or append to the file
```

Comment: Hello Grant. I flipped the worker's ReportProgress ahead of the conversion and saw some slight visual improvement. PDFText is Apache PDFBox's text stripper and it's very cpu intensive. Especially since it's taking a really long time to perform the conversion, I wanted to give the user some visual clue that the conversion was taking place behind the scene. It's unfortunate that the user still won't receive a notification until after the PDF is converted to a text file. I do appreciate the tip regarding saving the text file using the file path.

Comment: Hello Grant. That was a good suggestion, although I modified it a bit. I left the progressBar Style at Block, but added a label tied to the ProgressPercentage to give an additional visual que to the user. I set the label's text to display the percentage. Now, they can see the percentage climb to 100% and then clear. Thanks again.